# After voting results not showing in poll enhancements drupal 7

Tags: 7, rating

I have finally found a module to improve Poll so that will allow multiple users from one IP to vote, but I accountered a bigger problem, the results are not show after you press submit button. What should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have not used the module but have you also tried [Advanced Poll](http://drupal.org/project/advpoll)? It allows either Normal (handled by default Vote API settings), By Cookie and Unlimited (Allows those with permission to vote on polls to vote as many times as they wish). The module is under active development and is full of functionalities. Give it try to see if it can meet your needs.

Comment: Advanced Poll as well gives an error. Can you tell me any hook functions or  overrides to stop core poll module from registering users IP and Sessions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know but maybe you could try asking in the issue queue of Voting API if you are going to use a module that makes use of it.